# Trying to calculate a field with code block but it is not filling the fields

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, python-parser

I am using ArcGIS Pro calculate field. With this I want to fill the null values of a new field from another field using if and elif statements. The other field is "yearsINT" which is a short year field while the "NewField" is just a text to fill depending on the value of the year. The code I have is the following:
This is for the field to be calculated

```
Reclass(!NewField!)
```

This is the codeblock:

```
def Reclass(NewField):
       if yearsINT > 2009:
           return  "2009–present"
       elif (yearsINT > 1999 and yearsINT < 2009):
           return "1999–2009"
       elif yearsINT < 1999:
           return "1999 before"
```

I get no errors but it does not fill the NewField.

Am I using Reclass correctly?

There wasn't much literature if this was the correct way to fill in new fields.

Comment: You want to pass in `yearsINT` into the function, not `NewField`.  In both the calculator expression and the function definition

Comment: @mikewatt wow...that was it. Thank you! I guess I haven't dealt with Python in a while, bit confusing since I thought it would had made sense to use the field I am filling up there.